# Reload content script on url change

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a very simple chrome extension which basically add some text to specific pages, is working fine, but only on first loading and when i refresh the page.

The page have originally some real time filtering which update the results and the url, but because don't refresh the page, my script doesn't work.

I try to fix it using the `background` feature but maybe there are some simple thing i can do to force execute the script when the is some change on the page.

This is the current content of the `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Extension description",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["contentList.js"],
      "matches": ["https://www.test.com/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).